# Python loading txt file and split lines by position in line

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

I am new here and a python beginner. I received a text file containing 100k lines each containing 120 characters. Every line is representing data for 14 columns but as some values are shorter the other they are filled up with blank. That way I don´t have a separator like ",". If I would choose blank as separator, the values would not go to the correct column.

Lines are like

1. Character 1:O or L
2. Character 2-5:Year
3. Character 6-13:Name of Month
4. Character 14-21:Brand of car
5. Character 22:.

```
O2020august  Opel    .
L2015may     BMW     .
L2016april   Mercedes.
O2021january Opel    .
L2023februaryAudi    .
```

I am stuck with

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', index_col=0, header = None)
print (data)
```

I am happy for any approach suggested. Doesn´t need to be pandas.

Cheers Jeanny

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Let me just provide the little hint `brand = line[14:22].rstrip()`.

Comment: Hey @Prune, I am sorry I didn´t want to use this site as a tutorial, but I honastly don´t know how to continue. I check differnt forums as well. Like stated I don´t know what I could use as separator. I tried to apprach buy creating a list but that is getting me nowhere. As is is separating on blank values.  file = open('text.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    print(columns)

Comment: @TimRoberts: Thanks that helps!

Comment: Being "stuck" does not make the problem appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Again, refer to the posting guidelines.  It seems like you need a general help site, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a simple helper function that does the job for you.

```py
def split_by_pos(string_to_split, *args):
    """
    Splits a string at the given positions
    :param string_to_split: the string to be split
    :param args: the positions where the function will split the string.
    :return: the splitted string as a tuple
    """
    return_value = list()
    args = sorted(args)
    previous = 0
    for position in args:
        return_value.append(string_to_split[previous:position])
        previous = position
    return_value.append(string_to_split[previous:])
    return tuple(return_value)


with open("a_random_file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    
for line in lines:
    print(split_by_pos(line, 1, 5, 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like that can solve your problem.

```
for line in txt:
   #line should point something like that => "O2020august Opel"
   print(line)
   s1 = line[:1]
   s2 = line[1:5]
   s3 = line[5:13]
   .
   .
   .
   print(s1, s2, s3)
```

You can use `readline` and `readlines` methods of Python file read API.

Comment: Since he is a beginner, I suggest explaining how to open a file as well :)